# Error when installing theme - "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in..."

Tags: themes, errors, installation

I'm trying to upload and install a custom theme, and have encountered an error I've not seen before.

> Warning: copy(/home/content/38/7184638/html/wp-content/upgrade/SEWS_theme1/SEWS_theme/img/border.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/38/7184638/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 200
>
> Warning: copy(/home/content/38/7184638/html/wp-content/upgrade/SEWS_theme1/SEWS_theme/img/border.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/38/7184638/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 200
>
> Could not copy file. /home/content/38/7184638/html/wp-content/themes/SEWS_theme/img/border.png

Theme install failed.

I'm not at all sure what that means, any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: How are you attempting to upload/install the Theme? Are you using the WP-Admin UI, or are you using FTP? If you use FTP, can you upload the Theme? If so, can you see/activate the Theme from the WP-Admin UI? Do you get this same problem with any other Theme (such as one hosted in the official directory)?

Answer (score 1):

> Could not copy file.
>   /home/content/38/7184638/html/wp-content/themes/SEWS_theme/img/border.png

because there is no file border.png. Maybe it is not included in the zip file. Or there was errors while unzipping the zip archive.

The directory in the errpor message is 'wp-content/upgrade/', so I think you do not upload and install a theme, you try to update a already installed theme. WordPress first unzip the theme from the zip archive into a directory (wp-content/upgrade/) and then copy the files into the theme directory.

Download the zip archive and check it manually. Try to delete the old theme (backup first!) with FTP and then upload and install the new version.